# Communicating with a server application configuring Spring containerization from my main application container

Tags: docker, spring-cloud, docker-network

I have a problem communicating between docker containers.
I have two applications.

- One application is the configuration server and exposes the various application.properties files.
- A main application that retrieves these properties using Spring cloud config.

Both applications are containerized via docker. Both applications must run on the same server. For reasons I have two jobs in my pipeline. One for testing and the other for deployment. In the test job, I build the image of my main application via Docker build. In the dockerfile of my main application, I have the RUN command mvn clean install -Dspring.profiles.active=$profil ( profile defining which properties to load between dev and prod ) .
The configuration application is already running on port 8888 of the host. When building the application, it crashes because it hits a Timeout on the https://xxx.xxx.xxx:8888/main-app/dev url. Whereas on my local machine, when building via docker build, it manages to connect.

I think it's because this container can't communicate with its host. But I don't know how to get it to communicate. Without going through a docker-compose

I would like the docker build command to be ok and to know how to make two docker containers communicate during a docker build.

Minimal reproductible :

```
server:
   port: 9101
spring:
  application:
    name: config-server
  cloud:
    compatibility-verifier:
     enabled: false
    config:
      server:
       encrypt:
          enabled: false
       git:
          clone-on-start: true
          uri: uri repo git 
       ignoreLocalSshSettings: true
```

The main of your app server config:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class ServerConfigApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ServerConfigApplication.class, args);
   }

}
```

You can lauch the

The docker file of your principal apps :

```
FROM maven:3.9.4-eclipse-temurin-17-alpine as build
ARG profil=DEV
WORKDIR main-app
COPY . .
RUN echo "Building image with profil : $profil"
RUN mvn clean install -Dspring.profiles.active=$profil

FROM eclipse-temurin:17-alpine
WORKDIR app
COPY --from=build /main-app/target/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar .
EXPOSE 8082
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

The mvn clean install command installs all dependencies by communicating with the external maven repo . but I add a profile so that it retrieves properties for its operation in the configuration server . I've specified the retrieval url in bootstrap.properties

```
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9101
```

Comment: Containers can't communicate during the image build.  Imagine the image build stage as producing a jar file that you're going to run on another system; whatever state the interaction might have affected will be lost.  You say this works in one environment, though; can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: But during construction it can communicate with the outside to download dependencies. So I just ask it to connect to the host server by specifying its ip address and then the port so that it can retrieve the properties.